# org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, jsch

I have a spring batch application where batch runs continuously to pull data from another server through SFTP. In log continuously I'm getting below mentioned error but it seems batch is working as expected its pulling file from another server without any issue. I don't know why its throwing error in log. And strange is same code is not throwing any error in qa env its only throwing error in prod.
Batch is doing its job but its throwing error also in log.

Can anyone please provide me suggestion how to get rid of this error?

Below is he code for creating sessionfactory.

```
**public SessionFactory<LsEntry> pimSftpSessionFactory() {
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(
                sftpProperties.privateKeyLocation);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,password");
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sftpSessionFactory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sftpSessionFactory.setHost(sftpProperties.hostName);
        sftpSessionFactory.setPort(sftpProperties.port);
        sftpSessionFactory.setUser(sftpProperties.username);
        sftpSessionFactory.setKnownHosts(sftpProperties.knownHosts);
        sftpSessionFactory.setPrivateKey(resource);
        sftpSessionFactory.setSessionConfig(config);
        return sftpSessionFactory;**
```

Pom entry:

```
 **<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
    </dependency>**
```

### Error:

```
03 Sep 2020 01:47:56.688 ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing remote to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:303)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:200)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:224)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to obtain pooled item; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:178)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:441)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:264)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create SFTP Session
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:393)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:188)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:169)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to connect
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:273)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:388)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:315)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:152)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:145)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:268)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:307)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2909)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2935)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:262)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: any firewall in between ? This is most likely a network issue.

Comment: from source linux server when I am connecting to destination linux server using sftp command its getting connected.

Comment: Can you share the properties file?

Comment: I guess nothing spring related. There is a connection problem between ftp server.